# Equal column heights problem

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement equal column heights on my new website. If you look at the following page

http://blackburnseo.com/ensor_install/hedgehog-gutter-brush

The left column doesn't auto stretch.

I've tried a few jquery auto heigh solutions but they seem to break up my layout?

Can anybody recommend a solution?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Roger Johansson's faux columns article at http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/. I have used it several times.

What it does is it backgrounds the container and then the main section has its own background, the sidebar is clean. As the main content grows, so will the sidebar seamlessly.

Comment: This layout doesn't seem to work when the column content exceeds that of the main content, it shows the background beneath the main content. Try using firebug on the [final version of the demo](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/finished.html) to add some `<br>`s or something in the column, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I was afraid of that. The technique assumes the main content to be bigger than the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/xBZjG/), I wrote for myself, in every project where I need the heights to be equal. But if you can use CSS-only faux columns technique I would go for it instead. The plugin needs some updates to look more professional :-P

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. add an `<div class="clear"></div>` after you right menu
2. move your background from your left_menu to your content_wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Take background off `#left_menu` and put it to `#content_wrapper` with `float: left;`

```
#content_wrapper {
background:url("images/left_menu.png") repeat-y left top;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post:

[Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/7692-fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)